# ic_launcher_foreground not fitting

Tags: android, svg

I'm trying to make my new app compatible with the latest Android requirements, which means including an SVG version of my app icon. I was successful at converting my PNG icon to SVG, and I was able to include the resulting path in the ic_launcher_foreground.xml, but when previewing the result in the ic_launcher.xml or ic_launcher_round.xml the SVG is either too big, or not in the right position.

Normally one would apply scaling or transformation to fix that. Inkscape does this, and leaves the actual path values alone. But the android file format does not seem to support scaling or transforming.

How do I make an SVG path fit the 108x108 (or better 72x72 center) as required by Android? It should be possible to use any freely available SVG icon and make it fit, right?

Comment: Did you use the Android Studio Vector Asset wizard to get the SVG into your project? If not, what did you use?

Comment: I used an online tool to convert my PNG to SVG, and then simply copied the path data into the ic_launcher_foreground. But I also tried using an icon generated by the vector asset wizard. But in both cases I copied the path data.

Comment: It would help if I could really manipulate the path coordinates, instead of having a group wrapped around it with a transform.